# In Mysql database (PhpMyAdmin) Insert duplicate foriegn key problem

Tags: mysql

## 1062 - Duplicate entry '8' for key 'user_id'

I created two table one is 'tb_user' and the other is 'tb_service_booking' the primary key of user table used as a forign key in 'tb_service_booking'.
If i insert data into a table 'tb_service_booking' one time for user_id '8' successfully insert but if i want to insert second row on same user_id '8' ........So, it give me the error which is ( #1062 - Duplicate entry '8' for key 'user_id )
So how can solve this problem inside PhpMyAdmin

Comment: What kind of help do you expect with the information you gave us?

Comment: Please add your table definition, and the insert statements which fired the error message. The error message is self-explanatory so I am not clear why you would have issue with it.

Comment: There should be no problem here given your description of how your tables are designed. It would help if you added your table definitions as text to the question (show create table <tablename> then cut and paste.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem here given your description of how your tables are designed. given

```
drop table if exists  tb_service_booking ;
drop table if exists  tb_user ; 
create table tb_user(user_id int primary key);
create table tb_service_booking(id int, user_id int);
alter table tb_service_booking
    add foreign key fk1(user_id) references tb_user(user_id);
```

the following inserts work without error.

```
insert into tb_user values (8);
insert into tb_service_booking values (1,8),(2,8);

select * from tb_user;

+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|       8 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

select * from tb_service_booking;

+------+---------+
| id   | user_id |
+------+---------+
|    1 |       8 |
|    2 |       8 |
+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If your model is different or you are doing something differently you need to explain more.